# Altering the column names of dataframes in a list with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I want to add a prefix to the colnames of dataframes in a list, based on the name of the dataframe:

```
list1 <- vector("list", 6)

list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE))))
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {colnames(x)<- letters[1:10];x})
names(list1) <- LETTERS[1:6]
```

At this point, i want to change the colnames with something like:

```
    colnames(list1[[1]]) <- paste(names(list1[1]), colnames(list1[[1]]), sep=".")
    colnames(list1[[1]])
    [1] "A.a" "A.b" "A.c" "A.d" "A.e" "A.f" "A.g" "A.h" "A.i" "A.j"
```

How can i do this sequentally on each of the six dataframes? I tried

```
lapply(list1, function(x) {colnames(list1[x]) <- paste(names(list1[x]), colnames(list1[[x]]), sep=".");x })
```

but

```
Error in list1[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I guess its about cycling through the names of list1? Or how is it done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, you can use `Map`.

```r
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste(names(x), y, sep = ".")), list1, names(list1))
```

Here is another way using `purrr`. The `i` functions (e.g., imap, imodify) will pass the name of the list item in as parameter `.y` along with the list contents in `.x`.

```r
library(purrr)

imodify(list1, ~ set_names(.x, paste(names(.x), .y, sep = ".")))
```

Comment: Smooth! Why did you use `imodify()` instead of `imap`?

Comment: @Julian `modify` will return the same type, which in this case is a list. `map` will always return a list. So really it doesn't matter on this one.

Comment: `purrr` is about 30% slower, though.

Comment: I think the order should be like: `Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste(y, names(x), sep = ".")), list1, names(list1))`

Comment: @GKi On a second look, I think you're right. Good catch. Still representative of the general solution though so I am going to keep it for now.

Answer (score 3):

another way, if you have your dataframes already prepared and want to prefix columns with each dataframe's name:

```
## example dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = runif(1))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = runif(1))
```

```
library(purrr)

dataframes_to_change = c('df1','df2')

walk(dataframes_to_change, ~{
    df <- get(.x)
    names(df) <- paste(.x, names(df), sep = '_')
    assign(.x, value = df, pos = 1)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying `attr`ibutes might be faster.

```
Map(`attr<-`, list1, 'names', Map(paste, names(list1), lapply(list1, attr, 'names'), sep='.'))
```

Comment: +1 most people don't necessarily need the fast solution, but for those who do, it's nice to have it all in the same answer set